# Overlap div spans vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to overlap the blue div-span over a div-span-well vertically. See the attached image, is this possible in bootstrap?[image]

Comment: Any HTML Code you have got?

Comment: Is it possible in bootstrap? Bootstrap is nothing special, it's not a language, it's just css... and it is possible in CSS, yes. Have you tried looking at the code for the page you use as an example to see how it's done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Not only in TBS, but you can do it in any CSS.

Say, you have a **HTML** this way:

```
<div class="head-with-overlay">
    <h3>Lorem</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

You can use a **CSS** this way:

```
.head-with-overlay {position: relative; padding: 50px 15px 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 10px;}
.head-with-overlay h3 {position: absolute; padding: 5px 10px; background: #00f; top: -10px; left: 50%; width: 50px; text-align: center; color: #fff; margin-left: -25px;}​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thhPg/

Comment: I find it a little upsetting that OP accepted an answer before I even had time to finish mine :-(

Comment: @Codemonkey It is been 10 minutes since I answered. You should have had a lot of time! :)

Comment: I was making a pretty JSFiddle example... :-P

Comment: @Codemonkey Yeah, indeed pretty. Time matters here... :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to overlap divs is to use `position: relative` in combination with the attributes `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`. [Here is a quick JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9FLUA/).

Bootstrap just compiles down to CSS, so anything you can do in Twitter Bootstrap you can do in CSS, and the other way around.